# React cant resolve absolute path in VS2019 with a jsconfig.json file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2019

I have created a Asp.net core React project using the build in template in visual studio 2019

[image]

The project created a separated folder called ClientApp where the React project live. I have done npm init.

I have added a jsconfig.json file at the root of the folder ClientApp as follow.

**Folders**

[image]

**jsconfig.json**

[image]

When I try to import a component using the absolute paths defined in jsconfig, the compiler does not find the path.

[image]

and generate the error

[image: Error]

I tried to remove the "./" starting the path from "./src/components/*" to "src/components/*" like below

[image]

But the error is still there

[image: Error]

**UPDATE**

based on this thread https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353 , when configuring alias in jsconfig.json file, then you can use the new path aliases for module imports in your application. There occur any errors in your IDE or when you compile the code.

However, When you try compile the TS code into JS you won't see any errors. But as soon as you run your compiled JS code you will get an error:

For example:
Error: Cannot find module '@modules/user'
That's because JS can't resolve the modules for the declared path aliases... Based on the article it can be solved by installing a npm package called module-alias.

Comment: Can i know your folder path achitecture?

Comment: - ClientApp (is the root folder) and contains directly the file jsconfig.json. Then it contains another folder such as ClientApp > src > components.

Answer (score 0):

Which you have been set `baseUrl` with `.` you don't need add `./` in `paths` property

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
   "@Components/*": [ "src/components/*" ]
}
```

Comment: the root folder where the jsconfig file live is ClientApp then followed by the folders ClientApp > src > components. As you can see i directly pointed component starting from the root folder such as "@Components/*": [ "src/components/*" ].

Comment: From what i understood base url is where your paths should start, so if you put ".", it should refer to where the "jsconfig" file is living. Now if we want to create a path shortcut for "src" folder it should be "src/" and if we want one for "components" it should be "src/components". I really don't understand why the compiler does not resolve the path. Is it valid in vs2019 with a create react app project to have a jsconfig file inside the ClientApp ? Will it be used by the compiler ? I found this way on doing in the official documentation of microsoft vs code 2019.

Comment: I am using asp .net core 5. and ES6.

Comment: I tried your way and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you using CRA (Create React App) ?

Comment: yes, I am using CRA I am almost sure that the Visual Studio 2019 template for React is creating  CRA app. Actually, if we check the folders structure we have the React code that is under  ClientApp > src > components, which is very specific of a Create-React-App project structure.

Comment: I had that error experienced. Try use craco to use path alias on CRA, it's work for me

Comment: I tried the same setup on another computer and the same issue happened. I doubt its a bug. It must be some setup somewhere that is not properly done. I am looking for other option than craco thank you.

Comment: Is the Jsconfig file should be in the ClientApp folder ?

Comment: Yup, in root directory. Btw, when i was got that issue, it's appeared when i run react on linux or macos, when i run it on windows that work's fine. I decide use craco to solve path alias issue, for that issue i got frustated 2 days long before tried use craco. I don't know for other method solution without using craco

Comment: Thank you Wisnuaryadipa, I am also using windows, question => to use these alias do you need to configure it in jsconfig.json and also in a webpack.config.js file ?  Or you only need the jsconfig.json alias configuration and it is enough ?

Comment: Actually iam not using jsconfig, iam using tsconfig but i think that's identic. It's also work without webpack

Comment: Do you have discord? Maybe it would be easyer if we sharing experience with discord (sharing screenshot etc)

Comment: i found this article it seems that when we run the code it won't be able to find alias without additional configuration https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353